# how to upload all image files of a directory in mysql database using php

Tags: mysql, php-5.3

how to upload all image files of a directory in mysql database using php, it is possible to upload all file by selecting one by one, but can it be done by selecting only directory for all file under those directory.

Comment: Describe how you'd load a single image, so we see what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by many ways.
The simple things is to do use directory iterators.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getpath.php